# Retrofit response body null but status code is 200

Tags: java, android, sqlite, retrofit, sharedpreferences

I want to make a fitur to login, I want to make a feature to log in, initially I saw the response code shows 200, but when I saw the response body was null. I can still log in, but the logged in user data isn't saved. I used 2 db MySql and SQLite and im using retrofit and shared preference. And here my code

API Interface

```
public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Config.API_LOGIN_USER)
    Call<UserOrtu> loginUser(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
```

PrefUtil.java

```
public class PrefUtil {
    public static final String USER_SESSION = "user_session";
    public static final String USER_STORAGE = "user_storage";

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx){
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void putUser(Context ctx, String key, UserOrtu user){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(user);
        putString(ctx, key, json);
    }

    public static UserOrtu getUser(Context ctx, String key){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = getString(ctx, key);
        UserOrtu user = gson.fromJson(json, UserOrtu.class);
        return user;
    }

    public static void putString(Context ctx, String key, String value){
        getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    public static String getString(Context ctx, String key){
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(key, null);
    }

    public static void clear(Context ctx) {
        getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().clear().apply();
    }
}
```

Models
UserOrtu.java

```
public class UserOrtu {
    @SerializedName("id_user")
    @Expose
    private int idUser;
    @SerializedName("nama")
    @Expose
    private String nama;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Boolean error;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public int getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

SignInActivity.java

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @BindView(R.id.input_email_signin)
    TextInputEditText etEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.text_register)
    TextView tvRegister;
    @BindView(R.id.input_password_signin)
    TextInputEditText etPassword;

    EmailValidator emailValidator;
    PasswordValidator passwordValidator;
    Context context;

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Api mApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (isSessionLogin()){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            this.finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
        mApi = RetrofitBuilder.builder(this).create(Api.class);

    }

    boolean isEmail(EditText text){
        emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
        String email = text.getText().toString();
        return emailValidator.isValid(email);
    }

    boolean isPassword(EditText text){
        passwordValidator = new PasswordValidator();
        String pass = text.getText().toString();
        return passwordValidator.isValid(pass);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.text_register) void toRegister(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity (intent);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_signin) void onLogin(){
        if(isEempty(etEmail)){
            etEmail.setError("Email harus diisi");
        }else if(isEempty(etPassword)){
            etPassword.setError("Password harus diisi");
        }else if(!isEmail(etEmail)){
            etEmail.setError("Email tidak valid");
        }else if(!isPassword(etPassword)){
            String str = passwordValidator.getString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            loginAct();
        }
    }
    void loginAct(){
        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        final MaterialDialog dialog = DialogBuilder.showLoadingDialog(SignInActivity.this, "Updating Data", "Please wait..", false);
        mApi.loginUser(email, password).enqueue(new Callback<UserOrtu>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserOrtu> call, Response<UserOrtu> response) {
                UserOrtu user = response.body();
                Log.i("USER_LOGIN", response.message());
                if (user != null){
                    //Masih error disini
                    //if (!user.getError()){
                        PrefUtil.putUser(getApplicationContext(), PrefUtil.USER_SESSION, user);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //this.finish();

                    //}
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (response.code() == 403){
                    etPassword.requestFocus();
                    etPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_password));
                }
                if (response.code() == 404){
                    etEmail.requestFocus();
                    etEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_login));
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserOrtu> call, Throwable t) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.i("USER_LOGIN", t.getMessage());
                DialogBuilder.showErrorDialog(SignInActivity.this, "Gagal Login");
            }
        });
    }

    // this method to check is user logged in ?
    boolean isSessionLogin(){
        return PrefUtil.getUser(getApplicationContext(), PrefUtil.USER_SESSION) != null;
    }

}
```

And here's my result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK5HI.png)

Here's my JSON request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs4ln.png)

Comment: I can't find any issue in your reponse, body is not nul. In the screenshot, you can see the message = "Berhasil" right? Code is working fine. Please check your API, what it returns.

Comment: yes, the message is succes a.k.a "Berhasil" . But, user data in the form of id, name, e-mail does not appear and the value is null

Comment: Are you sure that your class `UserOrtu` has correct SerializedNames set? If yes then as AlphaOne said, check if your API is returning those data, you can also provide us JSON response for that request, so we can help you :). If you're using Retrofit then you can add https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor (if you dont have it yet). It will help you with checking what API  is responding to you

Comment: for the JSON request, I've added it to my question. Thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not representing same data as in JSON. With `UserOrtu` class it will works only if your response will have structure like below:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "nama": "Name",
  "email":"email",
  "message":"msg"
}
```

But as you can see 3 first fields are inside another object `data`. So your model should look more like:

```
class LoginResponse{
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private UserOrtu userData;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
}
```